# qRegisterMetaType usage

Tags: qt

```
  #include<QMetaType>

  typedef QList<int> IntList;

  qRegisterMetaType<IntList>("IntList");


error C2909: 'qRegisterMetaType': explicit instantiation of function template requires return type
```

C2909 says I need to define

```
 template int qRegisterMetaType<IntList>("IntList");
```

If I define like I mentioned above then I get the below error

```
 error C2059: syntax error : 'string'
 warning C4667: 'int qRegisterMetaType(void)' : no function template defined that matches forced instantiation
```

why do I get this  error ?

Comment: I am declaring these types in the header file. When I declare the same inside a function, say main(). I don't get this compile error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"qRegisterMetaType" is a function. It must appear in a code block.

Answer (score 4):

```
int metatype_id = qRegisterMetaType<IntList>("IntList");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(IntList)` before you can register it.